# Use multiple font in meteor

Tags: meteor, font-awesome

I have a paragraph and I need to change its font.
Here is my template:

```
template(name="test")
p.test this is testing
```

Here is my css

```
    .test
    font-size 18pt
    text-align center
    line-height 30pt  
    font-family "Lucida Calligraphy"
```

I have define `font-family "Century Gothic"` at the top of the code of css for the default font and is working.
But the font-family "Lucida Calligraphy" is not working ??
As I did some research I came to know about the font-awesome but I still have no solid idea So please help me out guys.
Thank You in advance!!!

Comment: First of all you've posted invalid code. The second one is that you shouldn't tag this question with `meteor`. Learn more about using external fonts, this question was covered many times on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Jagi I just post the part of my code not all the code. I forgot to mention that I am using jade-handlebars and stylus. I figure out the font but still there is a problem with firefox.

Comment: What problem with firefox do you have?

Comment: @Jagi I dont see the font in firefox. I can see the font in chrome,opera but not in firefox. I have define my stylus as following: font-face 
  font-family 'Lucida Calligraphy'
  src url('/fonts/lucida.eot')
  src url('/fonts.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
      url('/fonts/lucida.woff') format('woff')
      url('/fonts/lucida.svg#lucida') format('svg')
      url('/fonts/lucida.otf') format('opentype')
      url('/fonts/lucida.ttf') format('truetype')
  font-weight normal
  font-style normal

Comment: I encourage you to use FontSquirrel Generator http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator